# How to find Message Type from attribute name in google proto buf message?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I have protobuf messages defined as below. I need to find the message type from the attribute name. For example, when the input is "cfgMsg" the output should be ConfigMsg or CfgServerMsg.ConfigMsg (full name).

```
message CfgServerMsg {
  string name = 1;
  ConfigMsg cfgMsg = 2;
}

message ConfigMsg {
  string cfgName = 1;
  uint32 msgId = 2;
}
```

I have the below code. However, this is working for well defined types like string, int, float etc. and for messages it just prints "message" as the output.

I removed some code and presented only that is relevant to this question. So this is obviously not the complete code.

```
google::protobuf::Message *modObj = new ModObj();

const google::protobuf::Descriptor *outModDesc 
            =  modObj->GetDescriptor();
const Reflection *outModRefl = modObj->GetReflection();
const FieldDescriptor *field;

// Loop to iterate over all the fields
{
  field = outModDesc->FindFieldByName(tmp_name);
  std::string type = field->type_name();
  std::cout << "Type:" << type << std::endl;
}
```

Output:
Type:string
Type:message

However, I want to get the actual message type which is "ConfigMsg" instead of just "message". Is there any such API available from protobuf ?

I did check this page https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FileDescriptor.name.details thoroughly, but couldn't find any thing useful for this.

If anyone has done similar thing or know some thing around this, it would be useful.

Thanks,

Comment: `message CfgServerMsg {
  string name = 1;
  ConfigMsg cfgMsg = 2;
}` does not look like C++. It isn't even valid C++ syntax AFAIK.

Comment: @L. F, This is Google Proto Buf message. When this code is compiled using the protoc compiler, it generates C++, Java, Python etc. APIs. By saying C++, I meant, I generated C++ APIs and using these APIs in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some clue from another group and I could write the code in C++ to get the actual message type.  Posting the details below to help others.

```
google::protobuf::Message *modObj = new ModObj();

const google::protobuf::Descriptor *outModDesc 
            =  modObj->GetDescriptor();
const Reflection *outModRefl = modObj->GetReflection();
const FieldDescriptor *field;

// Loop to iterate over all the fields
{
  field = outModDesc->FindFieldByName(tmp_name);
  std::string type = field->type_name();
  std::cout << "Type:" << type << std::endl;

  outField = outModDesc->FindFieldByName(tmp_name);
  const google::protobuf::Descriptor* tmpDesc = outField->message_type();
  std::string subMsgType = tmpDesc->name();
  std::string fullMsgType = tmpDesc->full_name();
  std::cout << " Type: " << subMsgType
                        << ", Full Type: " << fullMsgType << std::endl;
  }
```

Output from the code:

```
Type: ConfigMsg, FullType: frrcfg.ConfigMsg
```

Comment: Thx! Very helpful.

However, some things were not totally clear like 'tmp_name' and 'outField'. I would change it to something like:
```
    /* Iterate over all fields. */
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptor->field_count(); ++i)
    {
        const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *field = descriptor->field(i);
        std::string name = field->name();
        const google::protobuf::Descriptor *messageDescriptor = field->message_type();
        std::string typeName = messageDescriptor->name();
    }
```

I'm sorry but I can not style this.

Comment: I thought some of code is self explanatory and I can't give full code for confidential reasons. I wrote the above code to look generic. i.e. if someone want to use, they can use while loop as well. So I just mentioned a loop. Thanks.